# Assertion when operator delete is called

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, assertion

When my objects are destroyed, I keep getting an Assertion failure in
dbgheap.c line 1399

```
_ASSERTE(pHead->nBlockUse == nBlockUse);
```

I can't find any reason why this happens. The pointers are properly initialized to NULL in the constructor:

```
CPlayThread()
{
  m_pPlayer[0]= NULL;
  m_pPlayer[1]= NULL;
};
```

This is the code that actually creates the objects.

```
if(pParam->m_pPlayer[0] == NULL) //pParam is a CPlayThread*
{
    if(config.m_nPlayerMode == modeSocket)
      pParam->m_pPlayer[0]= new CSocketPlayer();
}
```

The objects get destroyed when the thread is destroyed, and this is where the assertion occurs.

```
~CPlayThread()
{
    if(m_pPlayer[0])
        delete m_pPlayer[0];
    m_pPlayer[0]=NULL;
    if(m_pPlayer[1])
        delete m_pPlayer[1];
    m_pPlayer[1]= NULL;
};
```

I'm at a total loss here. It used to work fine and somehow it started crashing at a client's location after three or four days of running continously. At the same time my debug executable started asserting every
single time a player was destroyed. There are up to 96 threads that might be playing at any given time (with two players each thread, alternating - the players were created and destroyed as needed). So after looking for a solution and not finding one, I decided to just keep the objects for the duration of the application exectution. So now I only get the assertion when I close the debug version of the program (and presummably there is an unnoticeable crash on closing the release version, which is never because this should run 24/7).
I just need to know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: Setting the pointers to NULL in the destructor doesn't accomplish anything. The object is going away.

Comment: What type is `m_Player`? What does its destructor do? When is `~CPlayThread` called?

Comment: Stop using manual memory allocation and you may find the issue disappears.

Comment: If there are multiple threads, you may have a race condition - where one of the threads is still using the object when the d'tor is trying to delete it.  Make sure you are properly synchronizing access to the shared object(s).

Comment: You don't need to check the pointer for a null value before calling `delete`. Allowing the passing of a null pointer value to `delete` is explicitly required in the C++ language standard.

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks.

Comment: If `m_pPlayer[]` was declared as an array of pointers to a base class of `CSocketPlayer` and that base class doesn't have a virtual destructor, that would fit the symptoms.  (I expect that is the kind of thing the comment by David Schwartz is probing for)

Comment: @aritosteles You are doing a *lot* more than initializing pointers in an object and then calling a destructor.  It more than likely is the code you're doing between creation and destruction that is causing the problem.

Comment: @David Schwartz m_Player is a pointer to base class, and I can instantiate two different objects derived from that class depending on user settings. In the destructor it stos playback and destroys the CAsyncSocket-derived object it was using. ~CPlayThread is called on application exit, since I have an array of CPlayThread objects (they don't do much, other than holding data and pointers to the two player objects).

Comment: Smells like a [Big Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) problem to me.

Comment: So you are saying there is something like `m_Player = new <whatever type>[2]` before doing anything to `m_Player[0]` or `m_Player[1]`?  That is inconsistent with the code you have shown in the constructor and destructor.

Comment: Ok people, you are the greatest. @JSF was just right. I was missing the virtual destructor. Peter, m_Player could be initialized to one of two posibble types, just only once. My wrong not to say that right away. Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type is m_pPlayer[0] ( Like David asked. ) is it a base type of CSocketPlayer or is it CSocketPlayer itself. ? If it's a base type you need to make the destructor in the base class virtual. That might be related to your problem. If not, then the problem must be that you already deleted the object. This can be due to a racing condition, where 2 threads run the destructor with the same pointers. 
What also could be is that either the new or delete operator is overloaded, for example allocating from another heap. Guess that is far fetched  .... but possible ..